# Use tracking.js on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, color-tracking

I'm trying to do some color tracking on images with node.js. I found [tracking.js](http://trackingjs.com/examples/color_hello_world.html) to be quite suitable for the job. I've got the problem solved in the browser. As i tried to move things over to node.js, i realised that tracking.js depends on DOM elements to convert images to matrices, etc.

My usecase looks similar to this (from the tracking.js examples):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  var demoContainer = document.querySelector('.demo-container');

  var tracker = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);

  tracker.on('track', function(event) {
    event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
      window.plot(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, rect.color);
    });
  });

  tracking.track('#img', tracker);

  window.plot = function(x, y, w, h, color) {
    console.log('found ',color,' at ',x,y,w,h) // these results would be used in node.js
    var rect = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementById('bdy').appendChild(rect);
    rect.classList.add('rect');
    rect.style.border = '2px solid ' + color;
    rect.style.width = w + 'px';
    rect.style.height = h + 'px';
    rect.style.left = (img.offsetLeft + x) + 'px';
    rect.style.top = (img.offsetTop + y) + 'px';
  };
};
```

As I understand they present a gulp test that works in the repo, but i can't find a proper module anywhere.

Is there an elegant alternative way to make tracking.js run on node.js?

Comment: Does anyone know of an alternative to this package? sadly it seems it is no longer being maintained and (at least color tracking) does not seem to work on iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [latest commit](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/commit/c207e972a12cc2cb5ee83bfa7f0c1c9ce90a11c9) has absolved this problem (from [issue #47](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/issues/47)).

Comment: var tracking = require('./code/tracking')
ReferenceError: window is not defined?

Comment: Btw, tracking.js uses canvas and a lot of other related DOM nodes. You should look into extracting the vector calculations and adapt those. The whole point of tracking.js is to rely on the canvas/media to detect movement. I'm not sure how you can use node with this.

Comment: used the trick the testunit uses: require('vm').Script and `sandbox = function (files, /*optional*/sandbox) {
    var source, script, result;
    if (!(files instanceof Array)) {
        files = [files];
    }
    source = files.map(function (file) {
        return fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    }).join('');

    if (!sandbox) {
        sandbox = {};
    }
    script = new Script(source);
    result = script.runInNewContext(sandbox);
    return sandbox;
}; var tracking = sandbox('./code/tracking.js',{
  navigator: {},
  tracking: {},
  window: {}
}).tracking;`

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help (however little a part I played :D)

Answer (score 0):

As additional solution - you can take a look at [Webgazer tracker](https://webgazer.cs.brown.edu/#usage) - this one provides eye tracking out of the box. You also can select which tracking library to use (including tracking.js as on of the options).

**UPD**

I've created a version of `tracking.js` wolring in a worker in this demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/5sRi4H7nhypRy610Nx4K?p=preview , that's not a fully Node.js window-less environment, but close to that. Hope that may be helpfull.